# Injecting month variable on tradingview pinescript into security function

Tags: pine-script

This compiles fine

```
datecode="0625"
exchange="FTX:BTC"+datecode+"USD"
```

But if I want to do this it doesn't compile. =month returns 6 so I have to put a zero in front of it. But now datecode needs to be in quotations and I don't know how I go about doing that.

```
monthA=0
monthB=month
dayx="25"
datecode=monthA+monthB+dayx

exchange="FTX:BTC"+datecode+"USD"
```

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done in Pine.
[security()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#fun_security) requires the `symbol` parameter to be a fixed string, which doesn't change during script execution.
This is the case in your first example.
Your second example includes `month`, which will change during script execution, hence the compiler error.